# jQuery - click() not firing in IE7 on a div element

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, click, css

I'm building a "add tag" widget and I'm having a problem getting my click handler to fire in IE7. The widget works almost exactly like adding tags in Stack Overflow... as you type, it suggests tags. When the user clicks in the "add tag box", the text input needs to focus. My code works on all browsers except IE7... for some reason the click handler isn't being fired. I have a feeling it has to do with my CSS and/or HTML and the box model problems in IE7.

Here's my jsfiddle: (use IE and turn on IE7 (both browser and document)

http://jsfiddle.net/YYgy8/2/

Here's an example of the markup:

```
<div id="tags">
    <div id="editor">
        <ul id="taglist">
            <li class="tag">
                <span class="tagname">Tag1</span>
            </li>
            <li class="tag">
                <span class="tagname">Tag2</span>
            </li>
            <li id="tag-editor">
                <input type="text" id="tag-editor-input">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And using jquery, I'm adding a click handler to the editor that should focus the text input:

```
$('#editor').click(function(){
    $('#tag-editor-input').focus();
    alert ('click!');
});
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#tags {margin:1em;}
#editor {
    border:1px solid #ccc; background-color:#fff;
    padding:0.2em 0.4em;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
#taglist {
    list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0;
}
#taglist > li {
    margin:2px 5px 2px 0; 
    float:left;
}
.tag {
    padding:0.2em; 
    border:1px solid #ccc; 
    background-color:#F2F1B3;
    margin-right:5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1.3em;
    position:relative;
}
.tagname {
    display:block;
    max-width:100px;
    min-width:30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
#tag-editor {
    border:1px solid #eee;
}
#tag-editor-input {
    border:0; 
    padding:0.2em; 
    font-size:1em; 
    line-height:1.3em; 
    width:10px; 
    max-width:100px; 
    min-width:10px;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    outline:none;
}

.clear {clear:both;}
```

Comment: I've got IE8 on win7x64. For me in IE7 mode and IE7 document mode the "click" is well triggered when I click on Tag1, Tag2 or on the text input.

Comment: I've got IE8 on win-xp 32Bit. In IE7 mode and IE7 document mode the "click" event is correctly triggered when i click on Tag1 or Tag2.

Comment: The question had to do with clicking inside the editor box but not on a tag or the input... the idea is that the input won't have a border around it, but the editor does... so when the user clicks inside the border, it acts like a normal text input... same as in the tag editor for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update `#editor` class (`overflow:hidden;` is added):

```
#editor {
    border:1px solid #ccc; background-color:#fff;
    padding:0.2em 0.4em;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Now it works for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/YYgy8/10/

Comment: Has to do with how IE7 renders the div, when I add a `height` and `width` to the `#editor` class, the click works.
Strange that the div does show as a block, but doesn't function as a block element should.

Comment: Typical IE behavior. You should never expect IE to behave according to the standard.

Comment: Also worth noting. Adding `overflow: hidden` is merely taking advantage of another bug in IE7 (where the target is given height even though it doesn't have none). Hooray for bugs!

Comment: @GerritBertier `<li>`'s have `float:left` set. And that is normal that wrapping div will not stretch to height of child elements, but there is `clear:both` div which should fix that (and it works, but in this case - only partially).

Comment: Perhaps setting a `min-height` on the `#editor` element would then be a cleaner solution?
http://jsfiddle.net/YYgy8/22/

Comment: @GerritBertier IE7 doesn't support `min-height` :(

Comment: @MarcusEkwall But, surprise, it fixes an issue with a click... :)

Comment: @FAngel Wouldn't work in "real" IE7 though, since `min-height` is not recognized at all.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall Hm... have no IE7 to check, but according to [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) and [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=min-height) IE7 supports min-height. As far as I remember, it has bugs with it anyway.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall `min-height` is supported afaik. The implementation of it does not work, but the property is recognized.
PS: just setting the `height` might do the trick as well.

Comment: Setting min-height to 1em works, which I think that's probably better than overflow:hidden. I want the box to grow in height as tags are added and they clear to the next row, not that overflow:hidden does anything to change that (on IE7 at least).

Comment: @Redtopia actually, there is no difference in terms of groving height because of added tags. http://jsfiddle.net/YYgy8/24/ overflow:hidden usually used to stretch wrapper div once there are floating elements inside it.